# Asp.Net Core Spa, how to redirect after successful ConfirmEmail

Tags: asp.net-core, single-page-application

Got a Aps.Net Core spa (Angular) application and want to redirect to a page after a successful email confirmation and a SignIn. How to implement this (in the Identity/Pages/Account/ConfirmEmail.chtml.cs code).

```
        ...
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{userId}'.");
        }

        code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));
        var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false, null);
            return RedirectToPage("/"); // THIS DOES NOT WORK... AREA PROBLEM?
        }
        ...
```

The RedirectToPage in the code above yields an exception: InvalidOperationException: No page named '/' matches the supplied values. Perhaps "area" and a login related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it in combination with JavaScript in the ConfirmEmail.chtml file. In ConfirmEmail.chtml.cs I added:

```
var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code); 
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false, null);
    ViewData["Redirect"] = "/";
}
```

In ConfirmEmail.chtml I added the following change at the end of the file:

```
@if (ViewData["Redirect"] != null)
{
  <text>
    <script>
        window.location.href = '@ViewData["Redirect"]';
    </script>
  </text>
}
```